Resolving Keyboard Shortcut Conflict for Unused Import Cleanup in macOS
On macOS, when I try to use the keyboard shortcut Option + Shift + O to organize and remove unused imports, it doesn't work as expected. Instead, it inputs the special character "Ø". Is there a way to resolve this issue and make the shortcut function correctly for cleaning up imports?


On macOS, when I try to use the keyboard shortcut Option + Shift + O to organize and remove unused imports, it doesn't work as expected. Instead, it inputs the special character "Ø". Is there a way to resolve this issue and make the shortcut function correctly for cleaning up imports?

Is it possible to enter (recognize) the Option + Shift + O without producing  in the "Record keys" mode of the Keyboards shortcuts? You show it in the second snapshot, but without the ⌨ button shown, so It's not clear whether it is pressed or not.

My guess is that upon entering the key combination in the record mode you'll either see the resulting Ø or O/o, since the signal that reaches the VSC would be amended on the MacOS "keyboard driver" level, i.e. something like what is addressed in https://superuser.com/questions/151373/stop-using-mac-keyboard-option-as-a-modifier-to-character
